# VSCode Jupiter multiple line input

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I use Jupyter notebooks on VSCode using Python. I have a use-case when I need to receive multiple inputs from user. If I run the script from terminal (or just run this on ipython [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58594502/2517730)) I can simply paste one multi-line input, though on VSCode, I only can pass 1 line of input at a time.
Is there any way to pass multi-line input into a cell (without modifying the input or script)?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a **new feature**. I created a new [discussion](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/discussions/11059) in GitHub to vote on this feature, and I hope they can support it.

At present, what you need can only be implemented in `.py` files or `ipython`.

We can use `"ctrl+enter"` or `"ctrl+o"` to creat a new line in input.