# How to perform simple editing operations in ipython

Tags: ipython

When in ipython (the text only command shell, not jupyter notebook) I can't work out some basic operations. For example, if I have a line

```
for x in range(10): x += 1
```

I might want to split it into two lines.  But if I press Enter with the cursor after the colon it executes the code instead.

Also, if I am editing a multi line cell I can't work out how to execute the cell without moving the cursor to the final line.

How can you do these things?

I am using Ubuntu.

Comment: Does this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61646868/8508004) saying to use `Ctrl + o` answer your splitting line issue? It works on my Mac at least and that page I reference mentions ubuntu, too. As for your question about editing a multi-line cell you can then use a different key binding as discussed [here](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/13879#issuecomment-1369037341) to run the cell from anywhere in the editing and not have to be at the end. In my case on my Mac it was `Esc + enter`. As you are on Ubuntu you may need to try some other combinations from there.

Comment: @Wayne Ctrl+o does work! Any idea about my second question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Wayne and https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config/shortcuts/index.html it turns out that Ctrl + o is documented as `Insert a newline after the cursor indented appropriate`.

For my second question, it turns out that Alt + Enter works but I can't see it documented anywhere.

Esc, Enter also works but that is documented at the above link.

Comment: I'll have to look into the documentation myself. Thanks for finding the one you have so far!

Comment: I found it, I think [here](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/2/notebook/notebook.html?highlight=keyboard%20shortcut) in a older version of the documentation.